# one call on change of one of two inputs

Tags: jquery

I have the code below in a page, if one of two textfields changes a function is getting called with the values of both.
The code works perfectly fine, but in the interest of efficiency I was wondering if I can boil it down to a single block of code.

```
$('#popfrom').change(function(){
    var popfrom = $('#popfrom').val();
    var poptill = $('#poptill').val();

    defineDate(popfrom, poptill);
});

$('#poptill').change(function(){
    var popfrom = $('#popfrom').val();
    var poptill = $('#poptill').val();

    defineDate(popfrom, poptill);
});
```

Comment: you could give the inputs the same class and then just call $('.someClass').change

Comment: I should have mentioned that I know that I can "combine" them via a class but want to use he id's.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

JQuery allows multiple selectors, comma-separated:

```
$('#popfrom, #poptill').change(function(){ ...
```

If you find you need to work with multiple elements, it's often easier to use a class name instead. Add a class of "popfields" to your inputs and you can simply use:

```
$('.popfields').change(function(){ ...
```

Comment: Offcourse ... how could I forget!?!  The two elements already have the id's which I use throughout a larger script and I want to keep them recognizable, so I will use the comma-separated solution.

Answer (score 4):

Add them to the same class, then execute.

```
$('.popClass').change(function(){
    var popfrom = $('#popfrom').val();
    var poptill = $('#poptill').val();

    defineDate(popfrom, poptill);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Add same class to both fields and select them using jQuery '.selector'

```
$('.classOfTheTextFiled').change(function(){ ....
```

:)